# C# - function that fills an array

Tags: c#, arrays

relatively new to C#.

I've written a function that is supposed to fill an array.

```
    public static void fill_array(Array tierkreiszeichen, int startdate, int zeichen_laenge) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < zeichen_laenge; i++) 
        {
            tierkreiszeichen[i] = new int[zeichen_laenge];
            tierkreiszeichen[i] = startdate + i;
        }
```

I want the function to take the array name as an argument, so if I call it by

> fill_array(march, 30);

I want it to fill the values of the array "march" (I created the arrays preemptively)

So it's a rather simple problem. What I can't get to work is passing the name of the array as an argument. The compiler error I'm getting is

"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of System.Array.

Any help shall be welcome & thank you in Advance.

Comment: instead of passing `Array tierkreiszeichen`, use `int[] tierkreiszeichen`

Comment: Your intent is unclear. If I call `fill_array(march, 30);` what contents should the array `march` acquire? Please give an example.

Comment: John's answer was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace This:

```
public static void fill_array(Array tierkreiszeichen, int startdate,
                                                             int zeichen_laenge)
```

With This:

```
public static void fill_array(int [] tierkreiszeichen, int startdate, 
                                                             int zeichen_laenge)
```

Comment: Not enough to make it compile :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Jagged Array.

You can find example over here

http://www.dotnetperls.com/jagged-array